# return vs. print for a function where output is written to .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write the output of the following code into a .txt file.

```
import os 

def add(num_1, num_2):
    result_1 = num_1 + num_2
    result_2 = 10 + result_1
    return("Hello, World!")
    return(str(result_1))
    return(str(result_2)) 

output = add(1,7)
save_path = 'file_path'
file_name = os.path.join(save_path, "test.txt")
file = open(file_name,'w')
file.write(output)
file.close()
```

When I open the .txt file the only thing written is "Hello, World!"

However, if I change the returns to prints and have the output in a iPython console instead of a .txt file I get the following.

```
def add_2(num_1, num_2):
    result_1 = num_1 + num_2
    result_2 = 10 + result_1
    print("Hello, World!")
    print(str(result_1))
    print(str(result_2)) 

add_2(3,7)
```

I get the following output:
Hello, World!
10
20

How do I get all returned values from the function into the .txt file?

Thank you.

Comment: `return` returns from a function - you cannot execute multiple of them in a row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os 

def add(num_1, num_2):
    result_1 = num_1 + num_2
    result_2 = 10 + result_1
    return("Hello, World!")
    return(str(result_1))
    return(str(result_2)) 

output = add(1,7)
save_path = 'file_path'
file_name = os.path.join(save_path, "test.txt")
file = open(file_name,'w')
file.write(output)
file.close()
```

When you run the code above, once it hits the first `return` inside the `add`function, it stops running, so `return(str(result_1))`and `return(str(result_2))` were never processed.

To output the equivalent of:

```
    return("Hello, World!")
    return(str(result_1))
    return(str(result_2))
```

You would need to write:

```
    return "Hello, World!" + '\n' + str(result_1) + '\n' + str(result_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

only the first return is processed because a return exits the method
try

```
def add(num_1, num_2):
result_1 = num_1 + num_2
result_2 = 10 + result_1
result = str(result_1) + str(result_2)
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` will immediately exit any function call. But you could just return all of your results together:

```
def add(num_1, num_2):
    result_1 = num_1 + num_2
    result_2 = 10 + result_1
    return "Hello, World!", str(result_1), str(result_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the first `return` a function encounters will fire because `return` will immediately exit any function call.

If you want all of them, build a tuple, string or some other data structure and `return` it.

For example:

```
def add(num_1, num_2):
    result_1 = num_1 + num_2
    result_2 = 10 + result_1
    outstr = ""
    outstr += "Hello, World!"
    outstr += str(result_1)
    outstr += str(result_2) 
    return outstr
```

Or for better formatting, use .format()

```
    outstr = "{} {} {}".format("Hello, World!", result_1, result_2)
    return outstr
```

Or package in a tuple (or some other convenient data structure) for handling later.

```
    return ("Hello, World!", result_1, result_2)
```

Or if you wanted it returned exactly as you had printed it

```
    return "Hello, World!" + '\n' + str(result_1) + '\n' + str(result_2)
```

Each has its pros or cons depending on what exactly you plan to do with thereturn. Cheers.